# How to read an environment variable runtime within a RPM spec file

Tags: rpm-spec

I'm creating an RPM and for some operation during the installation i would like to read an environment variable and use it, how can i do that.

I tried the below in the post section but it is printing empty.

%post

%define myvariable %(echo $ENVIRONMENTVAR)

echo "The ENVIRONMENTVAR value is %{myvariable }"

Comment: It is very difficult _and highly discouraged_. However, in your `%post` stanza you have a full scripting language; you can do what you want. Your example, `%define`, will not because it is build-time. And if you try to move files, etc, **you will break your RPM** where things like verification will fail. RPM does not allow input from the user _by design_.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can execute commands with tic and get the envrionment variable with echo like below.

```
myvar = `echo $MY_ENV_VAR`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).